# How to delete default code from store url in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, store-view

On the magento 2.1.5 website i add new store view, and i have:

website.com/default

website.com/uk

i need remove "default" from url, for get this

website.com/

website.com/uk

If i set "Add Store Code to Urls" to NO, website.com/uk doesn't working

Please help me with this issue. Thank

Answer (score 3):

This answer can also be found in the Experius Codeblog

> https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-storeview-subdirectory/

You could run the second store in a subdirectory and depending on your server (NGINX or apache) how you can configure this.

Follow the following instructions:

**Disable Store Code in URL**

This Configuration setting has to be disabled to be able to use subdirectories.

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to URLS

**Configure Base URL**

Foreach Base URL you have to add the subfolder at the end

For example

> Global: http://example.com/
>
> Dutch storeview: http://example.com/nl/
>
> French storeview: http://example.com/fr/

**Create Subfolders**

Create a Subfolder foreach different storeview, for which you configured the new base url, in the pub folder. This is because all request for each stroeview ill go through this folder.

Example:

> mkdir ~/[pathToMagentoRoot]/pub/nl
>
> mkdir ~/[pathToMagentoRoot]/pub/fr

Create Symlinks in the subfolder to the media, static, opt and errors folders. This is necessary to correctly load the media and theme files.

For example:

> cd ~/[pathToMagentoRoot]/pub/fr ln -s ../media media
>
> ln -s ../static static
>
> ln -s ../opt opt
>
> ln -s ../errors errors

**Copy the index.php and .htaccess**

Now you only have to copy the index.php and .htaccess from the pub folder and edit these according to the entry points.

For example:

In the index.php change the following sentence:

> require realpath(**DIR**) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

to

> require realpath(**DIR**) . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';

Then edit .htaccess (only when you are running on an apache server). In this example there is only an explanation for nginx.

**Nginx rewrite foreach Storeview**
Add the following block to your nginx configuration foreach storeview:

```
location /[storeviewfolder]/ {

index index.php index.html index.htm;

try_files $uri $uri/

/[storeviewfolder]/index.php?$args;

}
```

Comment: Would be great if you could post instructions in your answer @Mr. Lewis

Comment: @George I have just updated the Solution!

Comment: @George you can now also find this in one of my codeblogs https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-storeview-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

### Disable Store Code URL

[image: Disable Store Code]

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to URLS
```

1. **Uncheck** Use system value
2. On Drop-down menu, click > **No**

> On my case under Search Engine Optimization

1. **Uncheck** Use system value
2. Use Web Server Rewrites > **Yes**